# Load http url image like a texture in X3DOM

Tags: html, http, x3dom

I´m learning X3DOM and I want to know why when I exceute in my browser from local this html code the texture (URL http link, no local image) isnt loading. The cylinder looks black.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://www.x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.css">
    <title>DOM Field Interface Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testbedDiv">    
        <h2>X3DOM Scene:</h2>
        <x3d width='500px' height='400px'> 
            <scene>
                <shape> 
                    <appearance> 
                    <ImageTexture  url="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B0GIfItPpsqjMEUyLU9Fam9aQ0E"><ImageTexture/>
                </appearance> 
                    <Cylinder ></Cylinder>
                </shape> 
            </scene>
        </x3d>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if anyone knows do it the same with "inline" tag for an .x3d http url link (no local too)

Comment: Because x3dom works internally with XHR which brings some restrictions like CORS. I don't know actually how it behave for local pages but at least for hosted pages this is a major show stopper when it comes to loading external resources.

Comment: I undestand that the only way of change that would be change X3DOM.jar to avoid CORS or change server to avoid CORS? Thanks a lot

Comment: You would have to change the server settings in order to handle CORS. This is due to the fact, that the Javascript (not Java) is run within the web browser. The underlying mechanisms are the same and can't be changed by adjusting simply x3dom.

Answer (score 0):

X3DOM runs in the JavaScript sandbox. That means without putting special code on your server, you cannot access files not on your server. In the case of local files, there is no server. You are restricted to local files only.

In my experience on a PC, you can use local files in Firefox and IEV11, but not Chrome.